# The method startSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback) is undefined for the type FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionmode

I'm want to implement Action Mode Compact in Fragment Android. But I get error **The method startSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback) is undefined for the type FragmentActivity** in my code :

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    getActivity().startSupportActionMode(modeCallBack);

                    return true;
                }
        });
```

get error at `getActivity().startSupportActionMode(modeCallBack);`how to fix it ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From this [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#startSupportActionMode%28android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback%29) `startSupportActionMode (ActionMode.Callback callback)` is method of **ActionBarActivity** which is used for ActionBar

if your `Activity` extend `ActionBarActivity` you can set like .

**For ActionBarActivity**

```
ActionBarActivity activity=(ActionBarActivity)getActiivty();
activity.startSupportActionMode(modeCallBack);
```

**For Activity**

```
getActivity().startActionMode(modeCallBack);
```

Comment: my activity extends Fragment sir ,,,

Comment: For now change this line.thats enough for your requirement

Comment: i get this eror 'The method startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (ActionMode.Callback)' ..

i has read the startSupportActionMode to compatible for android 2.3 and i want this

Comment: the parent Activity is  `MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity`

Comment: @user3216348 thats what i want..ok..change like my edited answer

Comment: thanks sir, line of that code not alerted again. but when i run code and click long item listview , i get error on log cat.  i must created other post again ..

Comment: @user3216348 ok..may be some other issue with listview..post it as other question along with logcat..

Comment: In fragment `mActionMode=activity.startSupportActionMode(modeCallBack);` You are life saver ;)

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
   int position, long id) {

  ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);

                return true;
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

add call to setHasOptionsMenu(true); in

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}
```