# ActionMode.Callback in Android 2.1

Tags: android

I want to use ActionMode.Callback in API 8. And I tried to change startActionMode to startSupportActionMode etc, but it still not working. The error is `Cannot resolve method 'startSupportActionMode(android.view.ActionMode.CallBack)'`

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                getActivity().startSupportActionMode(modeCallBack);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    private ActionMode.Callback modeCallBack = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Options");
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_msg, menu);
            return true;
        }

        ...
    };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The method startSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback) is undefined for the type FragmentActivity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926558/the-method-startsupportactionmodeactionmode-callback-is-undefined-for-the-type)

Comment: Are you using the compatibility library? This sounds like you are using the native library instead.